# Two point boundary value problem $x''+x =0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Side conditions x(0)=0 and x(1)=1

I know that I need to find the roots first but don't know how to continue.

Using $x=e^{\lambda t}$, the roots are found by $\lambda^2 + 1 = 0$, which gives us $i$ as the root.

Comment: Easier to start with $x=A\sin t$

Answer (score 1):

Your roots are

$$ \lambda = i,\quad \lambda =-i. $$

Now just construct the solution as

$$ x(t) =c_1e^{it} +c_2 e^{-it}. $$

You can simplify the above if you want. I think you know how to advance.

**Added:** As I said you can simplify the above answer to the form

> $$ x(t) = A\sin(t) + B\cos(t). $$

Comment: How do the side conditions come into play?

Comment: @grayQuant: You need to use them to find $A$ and $B$.